# What is the relation between $\int_1^\infty f<\infty$ and $\int_1^\infty f^2<\infty$ where $f\geq 0$?

Tags: integration

What is the relation between $\int_1^\infty f<\infty$ and $\int_1^\infty f^2<\infty$ where $f\geq 0$?

The example $f(x)=1/x$ shows that ``$\int_1^\infty f^2<\infty$ implies $\int_1^\infty f<\infty$'' is wrong.

What about the converse statement? that is, whether ``$\int_1^\infty f<\infty$ could ensure $\int_1^\infty f^2<\infty$. Notice that here $f\geq 0$, and no decreasing assumption.

Comment: If the measure of the full space over which you integrate is finite (e.g., a bounded interval with the Lebesgue measure), then there is an implication due to the Cauchy inequality. Namely, $\int f^2 < \infty$ implies  $\int f < \infty$.  In this case, the measure of the space in infinite, and then there is no implication in either direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac 1  {\sqrt {x-1}}$ when $1<x<2$ and $0$ when $x \geq 2$. Then $\int_1^{\infty} f<\infty$ but $\int_1^{\infty} f^{2}=\infty$